# Entity Framework Core Two Objects as Primary Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a model which is used for managing friend relationships. It looks as follows:

```
public class Relationship
{   
   [Required]
   public User User { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public User Friend { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public DateTimeOffset RelationshipInitializationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Users will have multiple records for their ID and there will be multiple records with the same FriendID so defining either of these as a key is a no-go. I would like the key to be a composite between User and Friend but when I define it like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Relationship>().HasKey(r => new { r.User, r.Friend });
```

I get an error that states:

```
The property 'Relationship.User' is of type 'User' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

How should I go about this to create the primary key that will link with a user and friend object. I didn't have any issues with my other objects having typed properties and I don't have an issue if I add an arbitrary key to the Relationship model. Thanks in advance

Comment: By providing explicit `FriendId` and `UserId` properties in your models and using these for your key.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The basic idea here is that your adding properties to the model that EF can use to make a relationship. Right you're trying to create a relationship of type `User` and that is creating an error. To assign a composite key each key needs to be a type compatible with a `Key` field, not a navigation property. So we add `UserId` and `FriendId` of type `int`, `string` or `GUID` etc. and create a relationship off those properties.

```
public class Relationship
{
    public User Friend { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public int FriendId { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset RelationshipInitializationDate { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

You can now define a composite key across `UserId` and `FriendId`. Something like this should do:

```
public class NorthwindContext : DbContext
{
     public NorthwindContext(DbContextOptions<NorthwindContext> options):base(options) { }

     public NorthwindContext() { }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
     {
         builder.Entity<Relationship>().HasKey(table => new {
         table.FriendId, table.UserId
         });
     }
     public DbSet<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }
     public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

[Source: Medium - How To: Entity Framework Core relationships, composite keys, foreign keys, data annotations, Code First and Fluent API](https://medium.com/radzenhq/how-to-entity-framework-core-relationships-composite-keys-foreign-keys-data-annotations-code-f4b238086463)

Comment: These properties don't exist in the code the user presented, a you probably need a little more explaining.

Comment: @spender Of course, still fleshing it out a bit. Let me know if you see any oversights.

Comment: @JSteward thanks for the help! I'm new to Entity so maybe this is trivial. Doesn't entity automatically create the table relationships when there is an object from another table as a property? So this would break that link?

Comment: EF can generate relationships for navigation properties but it won't generate a composite key. Which is what I think you were going for?

Comment: @JSteward Correct. I just want to use as much out of the box functionality in Entity as possible so I don't have to manually link the objects when they return if possible. I don't know if Entity does that automatically, but this gives me a base to tinker with. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to use HasKey method with two columns' names. My key propertty is private